# Ignoring files in a directory, but not the directory itself, in Git

Tags: git, directory, gitignore

How do I ignore files in a specific directory, but not the directory itself, in Git? I can add a line to the .gitignore file, but it'll ignore the entire directory. What sort of syntax does .gitignore support in order to achieve what I want?

Comment: What behaviour are you looking for? What do you expect Git to do with the directory if you've ignored all the files in it? Git doesn't track directories.

Comment: I expect it to create the directory in the repo. When I clone from the repo, the directory should be there, but empty.

Comment: Git doesn't store empty directories, sorry. Nothing you put into your gitignore will have any affect.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to add a `.gitignore` within the directory and add the files to ignore in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these

`dir/*` - It ignores all the files in `dir` directory but not it's sub directories.

`dir/**` It ignores all the files in `dir` direcotory and it's subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about how git handles empty directories, and actually has nothing to do with `.gitignore` (other than the fact that it's the ignore file that is causing you to have an empty directory)

See here [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)